# I am having connection error with post api in MERN, api is giving correct output at backend but inverse at frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, backend, mern

Hi I am learning MERN and trying to resolve issue regarding the API connection for a login page.
**handeLoginSubmit()** runs on submitting the login form having try n catch..

Entering the wrong credentials or the right only the try block runs
from the backend it is giving error but at front end it shows successful upon both right/wrong credentials

```
>front-end(react code)

async function handeLoginSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            await axios.post('/login', { email, password });
            alert('Login Successfull')
            // console.log('No - error');
        } catch (e) {
            // console.log('error');
            alert('Login Failed!')
        }
    }

----------------------------------------------

> backend code for express server with post request 


app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const userDoc = await User.findOne({ email });
    console.log(userDoc);
    if (userDoc) {
        const passOk = bcrypt.compareSync(password, userDoc.password)
        if (passOk) {
            res.json('passok')
        } else {
            res.status(422).json('wrong crediantials')
        }
        console.log(' user found');
    } else {
        res.json('not found!!')
        console.log('not found!!')
    }
})
```

Comment: Your frontend code completely ignores the returned JSON from the backend. There won't be an exception thrown.

Comment: @Pointy doesn't axios throw errors when the status is 4xx?

Comment: @Konrad it *might*, but if the wrong username is given that branch of the code does not set a 4xx status.

Comment: @Konrad according to the documentation it will reject the Promise but I don't see anything about throwing an exception. I could be wrong however.

Comment: @Pointy `await` will throw an error if the promise is rejected

Comment: thankyou brothers !! tried to handle the promises and ended up with the solution
@Pointy

Comment: @Konrad oh of course, duhh

Answer (score 0):

stored the axios request in variable and in condition check that variable **auth** and displayed the data coming from backend

```
>For frontend

async function handeLoginSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const auth = await axios.post('/login', { email, password });
            console.log(auth);
            if (auth) {
                alert(auth.data)
            } else {
            }
            // console.log('No - error');
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }

--------------------------------------------
>For backend


app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const userDoc = await User.findOne({ email });
        console.log(userDoc);
        if (userDoc) {
            const passOk = bcrypt.compareSync(password, userDoc.password)
            if (passOk) {
                res.json('passok')
            } else {
                res.status(422).json('wrong crediantials')
            }
            console.log(' user found');
        } else {
            res.json('not found!!')
            console.log('not found!!')
        }
    } catch (error) {

    }
}
)
```